# PHP: REQUEST_METHOD as basic error handling for html form

Tags: php, post, error-handling

I am using input from a html form to output arrays containing the value inputted. I would like to carry out basic error handling that states what fields were left empty, a error message if no fields are inputted and then if all of the fields are inputed. However, my code isn't doing as I would like. It works elsewhere in my code but I can not figure out the difference.

**EDIT:**
I am getting "Notice: Undefined index: ageChoice" and "Notice: Undefined index: colourChoice"

## HTML

```
<form action="profileFilter.php" method="POST">
    <p>Age: <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ageChoice" value="1">1 
            <input type="radio" name="ageChoice" value="2">2

    <p>Colour: <br>
            <input type="radio" name="colourChoice" value="Tabby">Tabby: 
            <input type="radio" name="colourChoice" value="Ginger">Ginger 

    <input type="submit" name="button">   
    </form>
```

## ProfileArray.class.php

```
class ProfileArray {
 Public function dataArray() {
                $profileArray = array( 
                    array(  'Name' => 'Toby',
                            'Age' => 3, 
                            'Colour' => 'Ginger',
                            'Gender' => 'Male',     
                            'Personality' => 'Gentle',
                                                ),

                    array(  'Name' => 'Cassie',
                            'Age' => 2, 
                            'Colour' => 'Tabby',
                            'Gender' => 'Female',
                            'Personality' => 'Playful',
                                                ),
                                );

                    return $profileArray;
                    }
            }
```

## profileFilter.php

```
include ("ProfileArray.class.php");
$object = new ProfileArray();
$profileArray = $object->dataArray();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$passedAgeChoice = $_POST['ageChoice'];
$passedcolourChoice = $_POST['colourChoice']; 
$errorMessage = "";

    if (!empty($passedAgeChoice)) {
        echo $errorMessage = "WARNING: You have not entered an age to search for<br>";
    }

    if (!empty($passedColourChoice)) {
        echo $errorMessage = "WARNING: You have not entered a colour to search for<br>";
    }


    if ($errorMessage == TRUE) {
        echo '<h4 class="error">You have inputted nothing to search for</h4><a href="catMatch.html" class="error_button"> Go back and try again</a>';
    }

//If there are no errors submit the form
    if ($errorMessage == "") {
         echo '<h4 class="error">Here are your full search results</h4><a href="catMatch.html" class="error_button"> Back to Homepage</a><br>';
    }

}
```

Comment: `$passedcolourChoice` != `$passedColourChoice` (letter case) and error reporting would have helped you out here.

Comment: Good spot! It's still not running though.

Comment: check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I think you mean to check if it's empty, then error, i.e. `if(empty(...` instead of `if(!empty(...`

Comment: ^ yeah, that makes sense; it's a logic issue. My eyes are tired. It's time for me to hit the hay.

Comment: `echo $errorMessage = "WARNING` doesn't look right. Try `$errorMessage = "WARNING` then `echo $errorMessage;`

Comment: However and besides what @JeffPuckettII pointed out, it's best to use `isset()` with radio buttons, rather than `empty()`.

Comment: @Fred -ii- `isset()` isn't recognising empty fields.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I have tried it as `if(empty(..` `if (!$passedAgeChoice)` and `if(!empty(...` but none seem to work.

Comment: `empty()` is mostly used for strings/lengths (text inputs), `isset()` are best for radio/checkboxes, take my word on this ;-) Use an `isset() / !isset()` against the POST arrays, rather than assigning variables to POST arrays (which is most likely why you're getting those notices), then using conditional statements after. You're actually working /coding harder than you should.

Comment: I tested your code and replaced `!empty()` with `!isset()` and it worked, along with the variable typo. However, a few adjustments need to made though.

Comment: @eainnem see what I posted below.

Comment: OK so I take out the $variable declarations and use `isset ()` or `!isset()` I'm not sure of the syntax to use `   if (!isset ($_POST['ageChoice']){
        $errorMessage = "WARNING: You have not entered an age to search for<br>";
        echo $errorMessage;
    }` But I know this isn't right?

Comment: Sorry never mind that last post, your messaged hadn't come through, I'll test it now.

Comment: @eainnem I've had a really long day and was about to go to bed. Seeing nobody posted an answer, I took the last ounce of energy I had left to post an answer for you below. I am now headed towards a well-deserved rest. 'nite nite.

Comment: Thank you for all your help @Fred-ii-

Comment: @eainnem You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isset()` and `!isset()` for everything here and you won't get any warnings. As I mentioned in comments, `isset()` is best used for radio buttons (and checkboxes).

- `empty()` is mostly used for string inputs, lengths etc.

Sidenote: `$passedcolourChoice` has also been replaced with `$passedColourChoice`.
**Variables are case-sensitive.**

You can omit `$passedAgeChoice = $_POST['ageChoice'];
$passedcolourChoice = $_POST['colourChoice'];` and use the below:

```
if(isset($_POST['ageChoice'])){

    $passedAgeChoice = $_POST['ageChoice'];

}

if(isset($_POST['colourChoice'])){

    $passedColourChoice = $_POST['colourChoice'];

}

$errorMessage = "";

    if (!isset($passedAgeChoice)) {
        echo $errorMessage = "WARNING: You have not entered an age to search for<br>";
    }

    if (!isset($passedColourChoice)) {
        echo $errorMessage = "WARNING: You have not entered a colour to search for<br>";
    }


    if ($errorMessage == TRUE) {
        echo '<h4 class="error">You have inputted nothing to search for</h4><a href="catMatch.html" class="error_button"> Go back and try again</a>';
    }
```

Comment: This worked! However my final statement `if ($errorMessage == TRUE) {...` this runs if there are any errors at all and opposed to when they are all blank. Any suggestions there?

Comment: @eainnem this is when you want to use `empty` - to check if a string is empty. `$errorMessage` is a string, so use `if(!empty($errorMessage))` instead of `if ($errorMessage == TRUE)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I thought [you were ready for bed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604467/php-request-method-as-basic-error-handling-for-html-form#comment62693605_37604467), I hope SO is paying you enough for all your hard work :)

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out using `if ()` and `else ()` Thanks again @Fred -ii-

Comment: Crap I did it again writing back without reloading the page! Thanks all the same!

Comment: @JeffPuckettII *haha!* - I know Jeff. But seeing that there were no answers given at the time and comments were starting to pile up, I figured I'd put one in. I did though tell the OP in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604467/php-request-method-as-basic-error-handling-for-html-form#comment62693980_37604467) that it was "nite nite" for me, and couldn't respond after since my head was embedded deep in my pillow. As for Stack paying me enough; *hehe*, well if I had a nickel for every comment I left and every answer I've given so far, I'd probably have a "paid" house by now ;-)

Comment: @eainnem I'm glad everything turned out well. I had gone to bed following [my last comment to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604467/php-request-method-as-basic-error-handling-for-html-form#comment62693980_37604467) last night, so I was unable to respond at the time. *Cheers* and you're very much welcome.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII *"this is when you want to use empty - to check if a string is empty"* - Yes, absolutely. Thanks for that comment Jeff :-)

Answer (score 0):

In profileFilter.php change two lines

```
$passedAgeChoice = (isset ($_POST['ageChoice'])) ?$_POST['ageChoice']:'';
$passedcolourChoice =(isset ($_POST['clourChoice'])) ? $_POST['colourChoice']:'';
```

Best practice: don't use global variables (e.g. $_POST, $_GET) directly. Try to validate them before use.